# How do I use list comprehension to find the smallest value per column?

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I have the following list:

```
List = 
[(1000, 1500),
 (2000, 2500), 
 (900, 3000)]
```

I want to find the smallest value for each column from the list.

```
Result = (900, 1500)
```

How do I use list comprehension to achieve this?

Comment: does the result have to be a tuple? i will adapt my answer accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need list comprehensions here, they don't really apply. You could do

```py
Result = (min(List, key=lambda a: a[0])[0], min(List, key=lambda a: a[1])[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do it, although it doesn't use list comprehension:

```
list(map(min, zip(*List)))
```

```
[900, 1500]
```

`zip(*List)` will transpose the list, and the `map` function will find the minimum of the two elements.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer said, you don't really need list comprehension.
But in case you really do, you could do something like:

```
Result = (min([a[0] for a in List]), min([a[1] for a in List]))
```

Comment: This is probably the most inefficient way to solve this. Not only this iterates over `List` twice, it also creates 2 needless lists.